# shouldChangeCharactersInRange logic

Tags: ios

I can't seem to figure out the best way to handle this.  When user presses decimal point I want it to move to next textfield.  The problem I'm having is it's displaying the decimal in the next text field and only works if I type a decimal only.  I believe I understand why it's only allowing decimal is because of the way i'm starting if statement, but I can't seem to figure out the best approach here.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *decmial = @".";

    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"."])
    {
        if (octet1.text == decmial) {
            octet1.text = [octet1.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:decmial withString:@""];
            [octet1 isFirstResponder];
            [octet2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (octet2.text == decmial) {
            octet2.text = [octet2.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:decmial withString:@""];
            [octet2 isFirstResponder];
            [octet3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (octet3.text == decmial) {
            octet3.text = [octet3.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:decmial withString:@""];
            [octet3 isFirstResponder];
            [octet4 becomeFirstResponder];
        }  
        else if (octet4.text == decmial) {
            octet4.text = [octet4.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:decmial withString:@""];
            [octet4 isFirstResponder];
            [myBitMask becomeFirstResponder];
        } 
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're only doing anything if the entire content of the text field being modified is exactly ".".  I assume that you should really be testing to see if the user has typed that in instead, by comparing with the replacement string:

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
```

You then go on to test each of your text fields in turn, without any regard for the actual text field being modified (the one passed into the function).  You try to check each one to see if it's exactly "." (except you don't, because you're using == instead of isEqualToString), and if it is then you replace that entire string by what ever the user's just typed.  Very odd indeed!

Based on your description of what yo want to do, how about:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *decmial = @".";

    if ([string isEqualToString:decmial])
    {
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:decmial withString:@""];

        if (textField == octet1) {
            [octet2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (textField == octet2) {
            [octet3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (textField == octet3) {
            [octet4 becomeFirstResponder];
        }  
        else if (textField == octet4) {
            [myBitMask becomeFirstResponder];
        } 

        // We've done the replacement ourselves and moved to the next field.  Don't allow the system to accept the change

        return NO;
    }

    // Default behavior

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Great this worked except the decimal keeps getting pushed to next textfield so when user enters then number the decimal is there unless the decimal is pressed then it does go to next textfield.  How do I stop the decimal from being put into the textfield?

Comment: I've modified the code. It should return NO so that the OS doesn't do the replacement (you've already done it).

Comment: Yup that did it, but now it doesn't except numbers.

Comment: Man thank you very much.  I was way over thinking that.  This works perfectly.

Comment: Doh it says voting up requires 15 reputations.  Guess I don't have that yet.